# Route [transaksi.index] is not defined. but the route already exists with route:resource

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I don't know why the error is being thrown, because the route already exists.

`master.blade.php`:

```
 <!-- Nav Item - Transaksi -->
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('transaksi.index')}}">
      <i class="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
      <span>Transaksi</span></a>
  </li>
```

`web.blade.php`:

```
Route::resource('transaksi','TransaksiController');
```

`TransaksiController`:

```
 public function index()
{
    $data = DB::table('tbl_transaksi')
            ->where('tbl_transaksi.nama_peminjam','like',"%{$request->keyword}%")
            ->paginate(20);

    return view('admin.transaksi.index',['data'=>$data]);
}
```

The error:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException

Route [transaksi.index] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\SistemPerpustakaan\resources\views\admin\master.blade.php)

http://localhost:8000/dashboard
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved, I just forgot to delete the route with the same name